# How to adjust width and add labels to X axis without a separete color key

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to plot a grouped bar plot using ggplot2, and i have more than one facet, each facet has different measurements:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(X = c("Low birthweight", "Low birthweight", "Low birthweight", 
"Exclusive breast-feeding", "Exclusive breast-feeding", "Exclusive breast-feeding", 
"Stunting (under 5 years)", "Stunting (under 5 years)", "Stunting (under 5 years)", 
"Wasting (under 5 years)", "Wasting (under 5 years)", "Wasting (under 5 years)", 
"Overweight (under 5 years)", "Overweight (under 5 years)", "Overweight (under 5 years)", 
"Anaemia (Women of reproductive age)", "Anaemia (Women of reproductive age)", 
"Anaemia (Women of reproductive age)", "Obesity (adults)", "Obesity (adults)"
), Year = c(2015, 2025, 2030, 2019, 2025, 2030, 2020, 2025, 2030, 
2020, 2025, 2030, 2020, 2025, 2030, 2019, 2025, 2030, 2016, 2025
), Percentage = c(14.6, 10.5, 10.5, 44, 50, 70, 22, 15.4, 12.8, 
6.7, 5, 3, 5.7, 5.6, 3, 29.9, 14.3, 14.3, 13.1, 11.8)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(X = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Percentage = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

I want to X-axis only for the Years that data is available so I kept it as `scales="free"` However still I am unable to adjust the width of each bar equally for facets that have missing data (year)

How can I adjust this and add labels to X-axis separately (for each bar label with it's year, not in separate color key)

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(X), y = Percentage,
                               fill = factor(Year)))
p + geom_bar(stat = "identity",
             position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ X, scales="free")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By replacing `X` to `Year`,

```
df %>%
ggplot( aes(x = factor(Year), y = Percentage,
                      fill = factor(Year))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ X, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
```

[image: BarChart]